# Github page build failure with no relevant error log

Tags: build, jekyll, github-pages

I am able to build and serve my jekyll blog locally without any error, but when I push the newer changes, I am getting page build failure error from Github.

```
The page build failed with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-build-failures.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

  https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
```

Here github repo in question: [https://github.com/prodicus/tasdikrahman.me/](https://github.com/prodicus/tasdikrahman.me/tree/gh-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your local build, you must update gems with a `bundle update`. You will see that you have an 'highlighter' warning.

About github-pages. I've just [forked your repo](https://github.com/statiktest/tasdikrahman.me) and it [builds](https://statiktest.github.io/tasdikrahman.me/) (with very small modifications) only with the same highlighter warning :

> The page build completed successfully, but returned the following warning:
>   You are attempting to use the 'pygments' highlighter, which is currently unsupported on GitHub Pages. Your site will use 'rouge' for highlighting instead. To suppress this warning, change the 'highlighter' value to 'rouge' in your '_config.yml' and ensure the 'pygments' key is unset. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-config-file-error/#fixing-highlighting-errors.

Can You try to change highlighter to rouge ?

Comment: Yes, it works after I change the highlighter to `rouge`. I tried running `bundle update` but it throws me a `Liquid Exception: cannot load such file`. Full traceback here [http://pastebin.com/LZzB8At2](http://pastebin.com/LZzB8At2).

Comment: Update: `bundle update` solved the problem after updating the highlighter to `rouge`